# Nested list duplicate

Tags: prolog

I'm confusing myself and it'll be helpful if someone can point me in the right direction. I need to get duplicates out of a nested list. I thought I could simply find out how to get duplicates out of a regular list and then make a rule for getting subsets then somehow combine them and it'll work but I think I'm confusing myself more by doing that.

Here's what I have so far, it deletes the duplicates fine.

Removes Duplicates:

```
duplicate([],[]).
duplicate([H|T],C) :- var(H,T),!, duplicate(T,C).
duplicate([H|T],[H|C]) :- duplicate(T,C).

var(X,[H|_]) :- X==H,!.
var(X,[_|T]) :- var(X,T).
```

Subset Rule:

```
subset([],_).
subset([H|T],L):- member(H,L),subset(T,L).
```

currently if I call `duplicate([1,2,2,3,4,a,a,a,b,b,b], X).` it'll return `X = [1,2,3,4a,b]` which is correct but I want to be able to call `duplicate([1,[2,[2,[1,[a,[a]]]]]], X).` and have it return `X = [1,2,a]`

Is my thought process correct or am I thinking of this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just flatten the list as a preprocessing step:

```
?- flatten([1,[2,[2,[1,[a,[a]]]]]], L).
L = [1, 2, 2, 1, a, a].
```

And then use your existing `duplicate` on the flatten list: `flatten([1,[2,[2,[1,[a,[a]]]]]], L), duplicate(L, X).`

Comment: Is there anyway to include that process in the rule so the user could just call the `duplicate([1,[2,[2,[1,[a,[a]]]]]], L).`?

Comment: @user3646479 Yes. Rename your `duplicate` to `duplicate_flatten` and define `duplicate(X, Y) :- flatten(X, L), duplicate_flatten(L, Y).`